# C++ container type that allows access to multiple bits by "bit index, size"

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, containers

I need to parse a binary message where the fields are bit packed. Basically I'm looking for a container that takes a sequence of bytes and then allows efficient access to multiple bits as unsigned values.
Pseudo code:

```
std::bitvector<char> vec{std::bitvector::lsbfirst, {0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF}};
auto value = vec.at(0, 5); // get the first 5 bits
```

Couldn't find anything like this in boost or the std containers (I looked at std::bitset, but that doesn't seem to fit the requirements).

Comment: Normally this is done by creating a struct that has members (can be bitsets) of the correct size for each "element" of the message.  Then you just copy the bytes of the message into a object of the created type and then you can access each member by name to get its value.

Comment: @NathanOliver Nope. Fields are of variable length and are optional. I have to parse the messages starting at the beginning. Predefined structures won't work.

Comment: In first step I would just write helper functions which are fetching required bits and keep `char` type in vector. If this is not enough I would wrap `char` in a class and provide respective methods to return desired bits. I do not see any need for spatial container.

Comment: @MarekR That's what I'm doing right now, I think. I'm building the final value by grabbing individual bits. That seems extremely inefficient.

Comment: @jpo234 That's the solution I have gone with on those unfortunate occasions it was required.